# Is SVNParentPath recursive?

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, webdav, httpd.conf

I would like to give students SVN repositories, and separate them by project, so that commits to one project don't increase the revision number in unrelated projects. Then I'd like to group them into directories by username, in part so I can remove old student accounts.

To get the granularity and other features I need, Apache + WebDAV is the system I intend to use, but I have a question: `SVNParentPath` lets me specify a directory to look for repositories in, but does setting that directive cause the system to search for SVN repos recursively from the parent path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC, no, this is not the case.

Given SVNParentPath /srv/repos for a Location /svn, mod_svn will expect the repository (eg test for http://bla.invalid/svn/test) to be at /srv/repos/test.

The code behind this is [here](http://svn.collab.net/viewvc/svn/trunk/subversion/mod_dav_svn/repos.c?revision=39074&view=markup). mod_dav_svn will consider the everything up to the second slash (the path always starts with a /), a repository name to be looked up in SVNParentPath.